# Do the numbers in state vectors have any physical significance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

I'm going through Lenny Susskind's QM: The Theoretical Minimum course and I was wondering if the numbers used to represent quantum states, like spin up as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and spin down as $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, have any physical significance? Do they have to satisfy any condition except orthonormality?

Answer (score 0):

For a spin-1/2 particle, the convention is to define the spin in a particular direction (i.e. spin up or down for a spin 1/2 particle) as the spin in the z-direction. That means to find the spin in the z direction, we have to find the eigenvalues of the spin z operator, which is given by

$S_z = \frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

where $\sigma_z$ is z Pauli matrix. Since $S_z$ is diagonal, it has the eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (which are already normalized). You could define spin up and down with respect to the other directions, and you will find different eigenvectors besides the one given above, but they will correspond to the same eigenvalues. Here is a list of those eigenvectors:

$
|\uparrow\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
|\downarrow\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
|\uparrow\rangle_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ i \end{bmatrix}
$

$
|\downarrow\rangle_y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -i \end{bmatrix}
$

where an up arrow corresponds to a spin $\hbar/2$ in the $x$ or $y$ direction and a down arrow to a spin $-\hbar/2$ in the $x$ or $y$ direction.

Comment: Right, I get that part, but I was wondering if they are pure numbers or they have dimensions? Where do the joule-seconds of $\hbar$ go?

Comment: Or rather, where how do the joule-seconds get in there? Are the dimensions always supplied by the operator and the eigenvectors are just composed of pure numbers with no physical interpretation in "reality"?

Comment: I believe those come you apply to spin operator. As in, $S_z|\uparrow\rangle = \hbar/2 |\uparrow\rangle$. I am not 100% confident but I believe this is the case.